# Sqlalchemy primaryjoin join argument alternative

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, relationship

In sqlalchemy, one can specify the *primaryjoin* argument to the *relationship* construct to specify alternate join conditions.

my question is: can this be done "manually" ie. is there an alternative (for the same results..) ? in the same way we can "manually" load (force eager loading)  using methods such as *subqueryload*, *joinedload*, *eagerload* etc..

ie. instead of specifying *primaryjoin*,

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if you define what's your definition of manual is, you can talk to SQLAlchemy via the ORM, it's core or even pure SQL, so there's certainly another way to do anything.  The question is, what is the problem you're currently facing?